# "Bad Request" when sending request to Socket.IO app via Apache

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, proxy, websocket, socket.io

### What I have

I have `Socket.IO` app letteraly from [template](https://socket.io/get-started/chat#integrating-socketio)

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('a user connected');
});

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

And I configured `Apache`

```xml
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName ws.domain.com
 
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3000/

  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /root/origin.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /root/private.key
</VirtualHost>
```

When I try to send request via Postman to `localhost:3000` everything works

[image]

[image]

But when I try to send request to `ws.domain.com` I always get `400 Bad Request`

[image]

[image]

### What I tried

1. I tried to configure Apache from [docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_wstunnel.html) this does not helped me
2. I tried to use `Nginx` and I configured it from [docs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html) its also does not helped me
3. I tried to rewrite server on `Flask` with `PySocketIO` and also with `flask-socketio`, and get same error

I am already completely desperate and do not understand what the problem is.

P.S. If this can be important, I use `CentOS 7`. I proxy the domain through the `Cloudflare` and there the websockets are of course connected

P.S.S. All my other HTTP applications on the server work correctly (via Apache), the problem is only in websockets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be very prosaic. As it turned out, the front-end had version 2 of `Socket.IO`, and on the server 4. Upgrading the packages helped to solve the problem